# Add line break to axis labels and ticks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to use long variable names on the x axis of a plot. Of course I could use a smaller font or rotate them a little but I would like keep them vertical and readable.

As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:20], b=rnorm(20), c=rnorm(20), d=rnorm(20))
df_M <- melt(df, id="a")
plot <- ggplot(data=df_M, 
               aes(x=variable, y=a, fill=value)) + 
          geom_tile() + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="red")
plot
```

here the x axis is just letters, but if I want to use the full name, the names use a disproportionate amount of space:

```
    plot +  
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) + 
      scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(df_M$variable), 
                       labels=c("Ambystoma mexicanum", 
                                "Daubentonia madagascariensis",
                                "Psychrolutes marcidus"))
```

So I would like to put a line break in the labels. Preferably in ggplot2 but other solutions are welcome of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can add your own formatter ( see `scales` package for more examples). Here I replace any space in your x labels by a new line.

```
addline_format <- function(x,...){
    gsub('\\s','\n',x)
}

myplot + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=unique(df_M$variable), 
    labels=addline_format(c("Ambystoma mexicanum", 
                        "Daubentonia madagascariensis", "Psychrolutes marcidus")))
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why the `addline_format` function is needed. Can't one just specify line-breaks directly in the labels? e.g., `c("Ambystoma\nmexicanum",...`

Comment: Don't even need to type in the labels, this works `scale_x_discrete(labels=function(x){sub("\\s", "\n", x)})`

Answer (score 37):

via `str_replace_all()`, replace `'foo_your_symbol_delim'` with a space delim ' '

via `str_wrap` from `stringr` library, with width prespecified at `40`, split at space delimiter `' '`, wrap the pieces, and paste

```
library(stringr)
...
+ scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(str_replace_all(x, "foo" , " "),
                                                 width = 40))
```

Comment: Because I was looking for a similar solution and created this more general AND efficient one.

Comment: Nothing wrong with trying to improve on answers to old questions! That said, your answer would be improved further if you used a less terse writing style.

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want a break at each space, you could alternatively use the `\n` (new line) within the call to `scale_x_continuous`:

```
my.labels <- c("Ambystoma\nmexicanum",
               "Daubentonia madagascariensis", 
               "Psychrolutes marcidus") # first create labels, add \n where appropriate.

myplot + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels= my.labels)
```

Note that only the first name (Ambystoma mexicanum) will break using the new line command (`\n`).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Joe's answer this also works

```
myplot + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Ambystoma\nmexicanum")
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

I'd also add to @SoilSciGuy's answer that if you only want to modify one label, you can do it inside `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
myplot + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Ambystoma mexicanum" = "Ambystoma\nmexicanum")
```