# ggplot2: add another variable as second line x axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this data.frame

```
> df
              var value percent
1 AAAA BBBB CCCCC  -0.5       9
2 FFFF DDDD CCCCC   0.3      13
3 BBBB NNNN DDDDD   0.7      17
4 NNNN MMMM BBBBB  -0.4      25
```

I want to add the `percent` and the sign between brackets "like this **`(9%)`**" as a second line x axis label.

I did it as below
[image]

using this script (following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901880/5420677))

```
my.labels <- c(
  "AAAA BBBB CCCCC\n(9%)",
  "FFFF DDDD CCCCC\n(13%)" ,
  "BBBB NNNN DDDDD\n(17%)",
  "NNNN MMMM BBBBB\n(25%)"
)    

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = value))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", width = 0.4)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = my.labels)
```

It is fine to do this for 4 variables only but if I have many variables, it will be time taking. I think there should be a faster/efficient way to do this for many variables. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my.labels <- paste0(df$var, "\n (", df$percent, "%)")

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = value))+
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", width = 0.4)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = my.labels)
```

[image]

Edit:

The above would not work directly if `facet-wrap` with `scales="free_x"` is implemented:

```
 p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", width = 0.4) 

 p + 
   facet_wrap(~var, scales="free_x") +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = my.labels)
```

[image]

To allow the labels to show properly, first add the custom labels back into the data.frame

```
df$lab <- my.labels
```

Then using the `facet_wrap` variable as breaks value for `scale_x_discrete` function:

```
 p + 
   facet_wrap(~var, scales="free_x") +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = df$lab, breaks=df$var)
```

[image]

Comment: What if it is a facet grid and I'm using scales = "free_x" to drop unused levels?

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. It is working fine now.